Adjust size of symbol after rotation
I want to rotate the \multimap command by 180 degrees. I tried:
\newcommand{\rotmultimap}{\mathbin{{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\multimap$}}}}

Everything works fine until I use \rotmultimap in a subscript or superscript environment. TeX does not adjust (that is decrease) the size of \rotmultimap as it does for \multimap. How do I fix this?

I guess instead of rotating the symbol you just want to reflect it:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\multimapinv}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\multimap@inv\relax}}% sure about \mathbin?
\newcommand*{\multimap@inv}[2]{\reflectbox{\m@th$#1\multimap$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a \multimap b \multimapinv c$\par
$\scriptstyle a \multimap b \multimapinv c$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \multimap b \multimapinv c$
\end{document}


(Are you sure about \mathbin? \multimap is a \mathrel.)
On the other hand, some fonts (e.g. newtx, newpx) have the symbol already as \multimapinv.
